# Replacing iteration with df.where?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am currently doing an iteration in order to multiply values of one column with a certain multiplier if they match a specific value in another column. For this i already have a functioning iteration:

```
for index, row in street_cal.iterrows():
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'motorway', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 130
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'motorway_link', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 130
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'trunk', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 80
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'trunk_link', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 80
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'primary', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 50
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'primary_link', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 50
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'secondary', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 50
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'secondary_link', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 50
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'tertiary', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 50
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'tertiary_link', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 50
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'road', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 50
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'unclassified', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 50
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'residential', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 30
    street_cal.loc[street_cal['street_typ'] == 'living_street', 'v_length'] = street_cal['cal_length'] * 15
```

Unfortunately this iteration takes quite some time, so I tried to come up with another method to do this and so I discovered `df.where`.

Quoting from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html:

"Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other. 
[...]

other : scalar, NDFrame, or callable

Entries where cond is False are replaced with corresponding value from other. If other is callable, it is computed on the NDFrame and should return scalar or NDFrame. The callable must not change input NDFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it).

New in version 0.18.1: A callable can be used as other."

According to this i thought that i could do the same operation as above using `df.where` like this:

```
street_cal['v_length'] = None    

street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'motorway', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_mot), axis='index')    
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'motorway_link', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_mot), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'trunk', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_tru), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'trunk_link', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_tru), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'primary', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_pri), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'primary_link', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_pri), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'secondary', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_sec), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'secondary_link', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_sec), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'tertiary', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_ter), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'tertiary_link', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_ter), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'road', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_roa), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'unclassified', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_unc), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'residential', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_res), axis='index') 
street_cal['v_length'] = street_cal.where(street_cal['street_typ'] != 'living_street', 
                                   (street_cal['cal_length'] * v_liv), axis='index')
```

But if i run the code only the rows with 'living_street' are done right and all the others contain numbers way too high in the 'v_length' column. I guess for the others the values get multiplied more than once and thats why they are so high. But i don't get why. The `df.where` in this case checks the column 'street_typ' if it has e.g. 'motorway' NOT written into it, so the rows that have 'motorway' in the 'street_typ' column should get written the `other` value into them, in this case `(street_cal['cal_length'] * v_mot)`, right? I guess I'm a bit confused about how `df.where` works.

Comment: Notice that you are iterating through the rows but never refer to the variables from the iteration.  You are performing the same dataframe operations over and over, once for each row.  You could probably eliminate the iteration and solve you problem.  However, [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433305/2336654) is better.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't realise that (I'm relatively new to Python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another suggestion; create a scaling map and apply it with `pd.Series.map`/`replace`.

```
scaler = { 'motorway' : 130, 'motorway_link' : 130, ... }    
street_cal['v_length'] = (
      street_cal['cal_length'] * street_cal['street_typ'].map(scaler).fillna(1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly